# How to use multi-line text in fcolorbox

Tags: color, boxes

I wanted to use multiline with \fcolorbox. I have tried using // but it is not working.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
      a4paper,
      total={170 mm,257 mm},
      left=20 mm,
      top=20 mm,
      }
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\newcommand{\wt}[2]{\underset{\substack{\textstyle\uparrow\\\hidewidth\mathstrut#2\hidewidth}}{#1}}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.6}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
    \underline{Ans}. $\Rightarrow$ \fboxrule=1pt \fcolorbox{black}{mygray}{
    (a) 9's complement of $(5842)_{10}$ = $(4157)_{10}$.\\(b) 7's complement of $(6423)_{8}$ = $(1354)_{8}$.\\(c) 15's complement of $\mathrm{(A96D)}_{16}$ = $(5692)_{16}$}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me to do this?Please provide the solution without using tikz package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as with `\fbox` the content is single line, but you can nest multi-line constructs such as `\parbox` or here I use `tabular`

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
      a4paper,
      total={170 mm,257 mm},
      left=20 mm,
      top=20 mm,
      }
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\newcommand{\wt}[2]{\underset{\substack{\textstyle\uparrow\\\hidewidth\mathstrut#2\hidewidth}}{#1}}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.6}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
    \underline{Ans}. $\Rightarrow$ \fboxrule=1pt \fcolorbox{black}{mygray}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    (a) 9's complement of $(5842)_{10}$ = $(4157)_{10}$.\\
    (b) 7's complement of $(6423)_{8}$ = $(1354)_{8}$.\\
    (c) 15's complement of $\mathrm{(A96D)}_{16}$ = $(5692)_{16}$
\end{tabular}}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can the Ans => be pushed to the center from the top of the box.

Comment: @PARTHKHAMAR just remove the `[t]` from `\begin{tabular}`  centering is the default.

Comment: Thanks...for helping...